# How to change json data in jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I have following json data

```
var data = [
    Object {  
        Data = 3, 
        Label = "Statement -2"
    }, 
    Object { 
        Data = 3, 
        Label = "this is a very long stat...s a very long statement"
    }
]
```

I want to convert it into the following:

```
var data: [{
    data : [[0,50]],
    label : "Comedy"
}, {
    data: [[0, 10]],
    label : "Action"
}, {
    data: [[0, 60]],
    label : "Romance"
}, {
    data: [[0, 20]],
    label : "Drama"
}]
```

Can any one help me?

Comment: How is the first code block even remotely connected to the second? `Data` in the first block is a single value, in the second it's a 2d array with 2 values.

Comment: 0 is constant. Can I make it possible?

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to format the data in the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Source JSON is not right.

Change your source JSON like this, and call method to transform.

```
 var data = [
 {  
    data : 3, 
    Label : "Statement -2"
 }, 
 { 
    data : 6, 
    Label : "this is a very long stat...s a very long statement"
 }]

for(var item in data){
    data[item].data = [0,data[item].data]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over your array of objects and use `toArray()` to get your array of arrays.

```
for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
 data[i] = data[i].toArray();
}
```

Not tested thou ;-)